# Why would this mailString autorelease be redundant?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

From a [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542252/what-about-this-mailto-openurl-might-be-causing-a-this-malloc-crash), how should I have known the "mailString" below was already autoreleased?

```
//
+ (void) sendEmail:(NSString *) subject withBody:(NSString *)body {
 NSString *mailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:?@&subject=%@&body=%@",
       [subject stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
       [body  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mailString]];
 [mailString autorelease];
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stringWithFormat:` is a convenience function that returns an autoreleased object.

I cannot recomment the [Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) highly enough. It *really* is worth reading, probably more than once.

Answer (score 2):

since mailString is not created by the [[NSString alloc] init]; idiom it does need to be released.

Answer (score 0):

You do *not* know that the object has been autoreleased.

All you know is that it is *not* your responsibility to release it.

You know that because it was returned to you from a method whose name did not begin with 'alloc', 'new', or contain 'copy', and you have never called 'retain' against it.

Reiterating what Eiko said - read Apples Memory Management Guide - it is very clear on this topic.