# How do you check a memory allocation by address in the XCode debugger?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I am trying to [debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542462/once-i-enable-zombies-how-do-i-hunt-these-mofos-down) some stuff and while [I'll also RTFM](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) can anyone tell me how to check the allocation of a memory address in XCode? The text I automatically jump to on the error is not immediately decipherable. In an ideal world I'd like to figure out the name of the variable (or at least its contents) that I just re-released.

An example of the error I'm trying to hunt down is:

```
2010-08-22 10:18:51.111 AppName[106:307] *** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x19f3b0
```

A screenshot would be lovely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The allocation's address -- in this case, `0x19f3b0` -- may be stored in any number of variables.

What you need to figure out is exactly which `release` or `autorelease` was one too many.

To do that, use the Zombie detection template in Instruments.   Screenshots in a second.